# I need to re-install a numpy extension every time I restart my computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, anaconda, python-module

I've run into a little problem lately,

I'm using spyder to code, installed through anaconda, and I installed a custom numpy extension not available through anaconda: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py_find_1st/1.1.1

The installation works fine, but every time I restart my computer, I'm not able to import it with spyder: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils_find_1st'`

Then, if I re-install it through the Visual Studio cmd, and restart spyder, it works fine, but it's a bit annoying having to do that everytime I restart my computer.

Would anyone know what the issue is here? I'm not very experimented with extension on python, or how they work.

Thanks!

*Logs of the CMD installation (I don't know if it's useful):*

```
D:\Chrome dl\py_find_1st-master\py_find_1st-master>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing py_find_1st.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to py_find_1st.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to py_find_1st.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'py_find_1st.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'py_find_1st.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\utils_find_1st
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\utils_find_1st\find_1st.cp36-win_amd64.pyd -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\utils_find_1st
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\utils_find_1st\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\utils_find_1st
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\utils_find_1st\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-36.pyc
creating stub loader for utils_find_1st\find_1st.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\utils_find_1st\find_1st.py to find_1st.cpython-36.pyc
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying py_find_1st.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying py_find_1st.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying py_find_1st.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying py_find_1st.egg-info\not-zip-safe -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying py_find_1st.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
writing build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO\native_libs.txt
creating 'dist\py_find_1st-1.1.1-py3.6-win-amd64.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' to it
removing 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing py_find_1st-1.1.1-py3.6-win-amd64.egg
removing 'c:\users\erlin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py_find_1st-1.1.1-py3.6-win-amd64.egg' (and everything under it)
creating c:\users\erlin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py_find_1st-1.1.1-py3.6-win-amd64.egg
Extracting py_find_1st-1.1.1-py3.6-win-amd64.egg to c:\users\erlin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
py-find-1st 1.1.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed c:\users\erlin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py_find_1st-1.1.1-py3.6-win-amd64.egg
Processing dependencies for py-find-1st==1.1.1
Finished processing dependencies for py-find-1st==1.1.1
```

Comment: How do you start spyder?

Comment: Seems you only install the package by its own installer; my bet is that it does not permanently register with the anaconda pythonpath variable and so is not found after each restart and thus reset of temporary environment-variables

Comment: I always start Spyder with the Windows start menu, I'll try to see if there's any information about the potential issue with anaconda's path

Comment: I would try using the Anaconda command prompt: `conda create` a new environment with any other packages you want to use (including spyder), `activate` this environment, then install py_find_1st using `pip`. Then each time you want to work with it, `activate` the environment then type `spyder`. Let us know if that works first, then there may also be a GUI way to launch Spyder in the correct env.